# Npm - Find the latest installed/modified package after install

Tags: npm

After I pull the latest updates from a repo I work on with other members and run `npm i` I get this message:

```
changed 1 package, and audited 2474 packages in 11s
```

How can I find which package changed?

Tried to find an npm command for that

Comment: Why not just look at the last changes to the package/lock file?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because it's pretty cumbersome, package-lock can introduce a lot of changes, it can be really nice do have an npm command that will list the packages by date modified/updated in node_modules